# How to validate presence of associated object in mongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, mongodb, mongoid

In my application I have Link model like this:

```
class Link
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :url, :type => String
  validates_presence_of :url
  belongs_to :link_bucket  
end
```

and LinkBucket model, which is inherited from FeedItem model (in my app FeedItem could contain  links, message, audio_track and so on, this is why I use inheritance).

```
class LinkBucket < FeedItem
    has_many :links
end
```

So how can I verify if there is a link before I create LinkBucket object?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the association unless the objects exist or are being created at the time.  But you can create a `Link` without having an associated `LinkBucket`, and then later create the `LinkBucket` and associate them.  In other words, only create a `LinkBucket` when you are sure you have a `Link` and you need to create one.  Does that help?